# Como guardo el valor de un COUNT para SQL para ocuparlo en un if en PHP

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, aplicación-web

Buen día compañeros me veo en la necesidad de pedirles ayuda ya que e intentado sin fin de codigo para solucionar este problema, les explico.
Tengo un sistema de citas en el cual con una consulta por medio de count a la BD puedo saber cuantos registros existen en tal fecha a tal hora el comando que meto en PHPADMIN es este y si me arroja cuantos registros existen SELECT COUNT(*) FROM agenda WHERE Fecha = '2022-09-09' and Hora = '10:30 am'; ahora dentro de PHP utilizo lo  siguiente y si lo saco por echo el dato si me lo arroja en panta pero yo quiero ocupar ese dato para condicionar con un if si existen mas 3 registros iguales me arroje que ya no hay citas disponibles pongo el código para que se entienda mejor la verdad ya no se que intentar les agradezco de ante mano su ayuda, cabe mencionar que si me llega a guardar mis datos en la BD independientemente de la condición osea que no me lo respeta

```html
   

$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM agenda WHERE Fecha = '$Fecha' and Hora = '$Hora'";
$result=mysqli_query($conexionM,$sql);
$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$data1= (int) $data['total'];





if($data1 > 3){
    echo "<script>if(alert('YA NO HAY CITAS EN ESE HORARIO)){ 
                                javascript:history.back();} 
                                else{ javascript:history.back();}</script>";  
}
```

Comment: Si haces un var_dump($data1) que te tira???

Comment: Si no funciona es porque `$data1` no es mayor a `3`, OJO, si es igual a `3` tampoco se cumplirá el `if`. Como te ha dicho @Yussef, pon un `var_dump($data1);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP Aunque tengas la razón tu forma de responder es antipática; no todos los nuevos usuarios saben el proceso que conlleva el ciclo de programación. Ser un poco más amigable no cuesta nada.

Comment: Ya utilice el var_dump pero aun asi se brinca la condición obvio ya tengo mas de 3 registros en la BD  con una fecha a tal hora mis horas son cerradas con opciones no es como un reloj que se pueda seleccionar cada minuto y el tipo en fecha es date no se si tenga algo que ver actualice mi código para que puedan observar las modificaciones y ver en que pueda estar mal les agradezco a todos su amable atención y aportación

Comment: no.. el var_dump que te pidieron es para que nos digas cuantos registros estas trayendo... si se saltea el if, es porque NO estas trayendo la cantidad de registros que vos pensas.. tal vez, estas pasando mal los parametros.. te fijaste como queda tu query?

Comment: Queremos ver la salida del  `var_dump`, ¿dónde está? El código no se basa en suposiciones, sino en resultados reales. ¿Cuáles son esos datos reales? Es por eso por lo que te estamos pidiendo el `var_dump`. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] y muestra la salida del `var_dump`. Y, ponlo bien, no es así: `$data2=var_dump($data1);` es así, simplemente: **`var_dump($data1);`**

Comment: Esto sale en la salida con el var_dump($data1);   C:\wamp64\www\Sitio\Operaciones\Insertar datos.php:22:string '20' (length=2)

Comment: Atiende las observaciones que te hace @A.Cedano, estas empleando mal la lógica, tu cosnulta solo arroja una fila, la cual como dato importante es **total**, que te trae el total de los registros con esa fecha y hora, tu condición dice **>3** para que entre deberías de tener 4 o mas registros con esa fecha y hora, si utilizaras **>=3** entrara en la condicion cuando tenga el contador **3** o mas, borra ese **var_dump** que era para que mostraras el resultado de tu consulta.

Comment: Si el `var_dump` te muestra `string '20' (length=2)` significa que la consulta te está arrojando un total de `20` registros. Lo único raro ahí es que el tipo de dato es `String` y en la comparación usas un nùmero (`3`). PHP es permisivo con eso al menos hasta antes de PHP 8, y debería pasar el if, de todos modos, puedes forzar a entero: `$data1= (int) $data['total'];` Si sigue sin funcionar, coloca en la pregunta el código tal y como lo tienes y borra caché y demás historias ... a veces se queda en memoria código viejo y te rompes el coco porque sigue funcionando con ese código viejo erróneo.

Comment: OK ¿y si comentas todo el bloque `<script> ... </script>` que tienes ahí y pones algo como `echo "Veo algo al fin... Esto me ha pasado por mezclar contextos, prometo no hacerlo en adelante... He perdido demasiado días para programar algo muy muy simple por desconocer algunas herramientas";`qué ocurre? De todos modos, deberías ir pensando en no mezclar contextos y usar Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript para comunicar entre cliente y servidor. Tu código, con scripts de Javascript en el contexto de PHP es del siglo pasado, hoy existen herramientas para evitar esas mezclas horribles.

Comment: Aparentemente colegas gracias a @A.Cedano en especial y a todos por su apoyo sirvio el $data1= (int) $data['total']; ya entra en la condición if solo  que se me queda en blanco por el script del if no se porque no me lo respeta pero si solo le pongo echo "no hay citas" me lo respeta muchas gracias.

Comment: Presta atención a mi anterior comentario, si implementas herramientas modernas podrás escribir un código elegante y optimizado. Supongamos que hay una restricción del tipo: *Si hay más de tres citas, no se deben admitir más citas a esa hora*. Pues bien, usando Ajax o Fetch tú puedes verificar esa condición previamente, deshabilitando esa hora, así, quien usa la App ya sabrá que no hay horas disponibles ahí, sin tener que: 1. Elegir la hora, quizá inútilmente, 2. Verificar si la hora está libre (un viaje al servidor), 3. Recibir la respuesta del servidor ...

Comment: ... 4.  Y quizá, llevarse la decepción de que esa hora no está libre. 5. Entonces, aaaaa elegir ooooootra hora, sin saber si está libre ... y vuelta a empezar en el punto 1, de nuevo a preguntar, a ver si está libre, y si no lo está ooootra vez, a decirle que no está. Desde el punto de vista de UX eso será una m.... de aplicación. ¿Por qué no mostrar ya deshabilitadas todas las horas no disponibles, a saber, las que ya tengan más de `3` citas? Así el usuario sabrá de una sola mirada a qué atenerse.

Comment: muchas gracias por tus consejos los tomare en cuenta para ser mejor.

Answer (score -1):

Brother lo que puedes hacer es traer los registros y luego contarlos, modificare ligeramente tu codigo y listo, seria una solución rápida(Usé la función count() ).

```
    $sql="SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE Fecha = '$Fecha' and Hora = '$Hora'";
    $result= mysqli_query($conexionM,$sql);
    $data= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $data1= $data['total'];

    //Aqui cuentas los resultados de tu consulta
    $cantidadResultados = count($data1);

    if($cantidadResultados > 3){

        echo "<script>if(alert('YA NO HAY CITAS EN ESE HORARIO)){ 
        javascript:history.back();} 
        else{ javascript:history.back();}</script>"; 

    }else{

        $query = "INSERT INTO agenda (No_de_Pieza,Nombre,Representante,Tramite,Fecha,Hora,Correo,Telefono,Despacho,Nacionalidad,Fecha_de_Registro)  VALUES('$No_de_Pieza','$Nombre','$Representante','$Tramite','$Fecha','$Hora','$Correo','$Telefono','$Despacho','$Nacionalidad','$Fecha_de_Registro')";
        $resultado=$conexionM->query ($query);

        if($resultado){
            echo '<script> alert ("LOS REGISTROS SE HAN GUARDADO EXITOSAMENTE.") </script>';
            echo "<script>location.href='../registro.php'</script>";
        }else{
            echo "<script>if(alert('LOS REGISTROS NO SE GUARDARON')){ 
            javascript:history.back();} 
            else{ javascript:history.back();}</script>";  
        }
        

    }
```

Comment: Hola bro muchas gracias por tu aporte pero se sigue brincando la condicion del if de echo en tu logica en la linea 4 yo le puse 'total' como nombre al count para que ahi se guardara el valor segun yo por que ahi como me lo pasaste no hace referencia a nada y en mi BD no existe esa columna

Comment: @joshua Pero fíjate en la línea 1, Mateo cambió la consulta

Comment: Proponer esto absurdo: `$cantidadResultados = count($data1);`. En primer lugar, mysqli devuelve un recurso al cual luego aplicas un método `fetch` para obtener las filas, en segundo lugar, si OP quiere contar las filas no hay nada mejor que un `SELECT COUNT(*)` para ello.

Comment: @A.Cedano correcto no tiene lógica, pero se agradece el intento sin  encambio cambie el código aun asi se sigue brincando aun no encuentro literal como guardar ese valor del count en una  variable para después ocuparlo en el if por que estoy casi seguro que es eso el proceso de guardado no es el correcto o al menos eso pienso